# Get full module path to class

Tags: python

I'm using a wrapper to dock a Qt window in a program. The issue is the wrapper takes any window class as a `str`, then initialises it later, making it not very pythonic if you have split things over multiple files (see the original edit for an idea of how it works, not important to the question though).

For example:

`import module.submodule.MainWindow`: The path is `"module.submodule.MainWindow"`

`import module.submodule.MainWindow as MW`: The path is `"MW"`

`from module import submodule`: The path is `"submodule.MainWindow"`

My current workaround is `module.MainWindow.shpw(namespace="module.MainWindow")`, but I would prefer not to be required to provide it as an argument

I tried making a function to parse `globals()` to find the path, and it does work quite nicely at the top level. However, I found out that `globals()` is unique to each import, so it does nothing when called from within my template class.

```
from types import ModuleType
import inspect
import site

site_packages_loc = site.getsitepackages()

default_modules = set([sys.modules[i] for i in set(sys.modules.keys()) & set(sys.builtin_module_names)])

def get_class_namespace(search, globals_dict=None, path=[]):
    if globals_dict is None:
        globals_dict = globals()

    #Find all objects that are modules
    modules = {}
    for k, v in globals_dict.iteritems():
        if v == search:
            return '.'.join(path + [v.__name__])
        if isinstance(v, ModuleType) and v not in default_modules:
            modules[k] = v

    #Check recursively in each module
    for k, v in modules.items():

        #Check it's not a built in module
        module_path = inspect.getsourcefile(v)
        if any(module_path.startswith(i) for i in site_packages_loc):
            continue

        module_globals = {func: getattr(v, func) for func in dir(v)}
        return_val = get_class_namespace(search, module_globals, path=path+[k])
        if return_val is not None:
            return return_val
```

Is there a better way to go about this, or could I somehow request the very top level `globals()` from within an import?

Comment: As far as I know, a class cannot know or enforce how it will be imported. `import module`, `from module import cls` and `from module import *` are all valid.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not bothered about knowing as the class is imported, I'm just needing it once a method is actually called. I was thinking something similar to the `inspect` module could be of help, but it's kind of a weird case where I doubt it's ever even been considered